# igraph unlist list of graph

Tags: r, list, igraph

I have a list of 8 graphs obtained by a list of matrices with the igraph command 'graph_from_adjacency_matrix'.
I would like to extract these 8 graphs into 8 separated graphs, but I don't find any information about such process.

Please find an abstract example below:`

```
A = matrix(c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7), nrow=3,ncol=3) 
B = matrix(c(2, 3, 3, 2, 5, 6), nrow=3,ncol=3)
C = matrix(c(0, 5, 3, 4, 5, 2), nrow=3,ncol=3)
Matrix<-list(A,B,C)
Graph<-lapply(Matrix,graph_from_adjacency_matrix,weighted = NULL,diag= FALSE)
```

I would like to have 3 new igraphs objects which correspond to  Graph[[1]],Graph[[2]],Graph[[3]]

Could someone help me?

Thank you in advance,

SOSA Sebastian

Comment: Hi Sosa, can you please provide a reproducible example of what you are starting from?

Comment: Hi thank you for your quick answer, I edit my post to add an abstract example.

Comment: So you want to do something like `a=Graph[[1]]; b=Graph[[2]]` etc all the way up to 8 and construct 8 new objects? That's normally a bad thing, and you should keep them in the list where they can be accessed by index number.

Comment: The problem is that after that on the list of graphs I use the function lapply(Graph,make_ego_graph). So I get a list of 8 graphs with 31 sub-graphs. I would rather have these graphs in separate objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also agree with @Spacedman that, for programmatic purposes, it will be easier to work with the graphs in the list or nested list form.

That said, if you want to dynamically assign the resulting graphs to new variables, you can use the `assign` function, e.g.:

```
for(i in seq_along(Graph)) {
  assign(paste0('g', i), Graph[i])
}
```

This will produce variables `g1, g2, ..., gn` corresponding to each of the list entries.

Also, as a quick aside, I would recommend avoiding the use of capitalized variable names. By most coding conventions (e.g. Hadley's http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html), variable names should be all lowercase.